# Как передать значение (объект) в метод класса?

Tags: javascript, ооп

Допустим у меня есть класс:

```js
class User {
  constructor() { // код конструктора 
  }
  method1(size // size - объект
  ) {
    this.width = size.width;
    $(".square").width();
  }
}

var a = new User();
a.method1(50);
console.log(a);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы при `new User().method1(50);` `this.width` равнялся `50`.
Но такой прием не работает. Выдает ошибку:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined

Что делать?

Comment: Сейчас я как угадаю, что значит "в моем другом коде"!

Comment: Сейчас.........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Что делать?

Передавать **два** параметра в `geometrySquare`.

```
canv.geometrySquare({
  x: 50,
  y: 50 }, {
  width: 100,
  height: 100
});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, дай вам бог здоровья. Спасибо за правку вопроса. Не думал что такие плюшки в stackoverflow есть!

Comment: @user370651 Пожалуйста. Попробуйте вернуть в вопрос Ваш код, чтобы было ясно, откуда берется `geometrySquare`.